# Webgrid MVC 3 conditional row style

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I am using a WebGrid to display a list of items,

I like to set the background color of the rows based on a condition. I want to set the background color of the entire row, not just one cell.

Any example?

thank you

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I just stumbled upon it and have an answer that I don't think is too hacky.  The previous answer supplied only works if the value you're using to conditionally change the background color is the value of a table cell.

If that's not the case, you can set a `data-` attribute for the first cell in your table rows using the Format property of a WebGridColumn.  Here, the first column of my table contains hyperlinked IDs.  I'm defining it in my code-behind (controller action in MVC) and I've added a `data-in-error` attribute from the `IsInError` property of my object.  You can set the value of this attribute in whatever way makes sense for your application.

```
new WebGridColumn 
{ 
    ColumnName = "Id", 
    Header = "ID", 
    Format = (x) => new HtmlString(String.Format("<a href=\"#\" data-in-error=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", x.Value.IsInError, x.Value.Id))
});
```

Then, using jQuery, I find all of the rows in my table that have an anchor in the first cell of the row, and set the class of that row to 'error'.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table tbody tr td:first-child a[data-in-error="True"]').each(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass('error');
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Is jQuery an option? If so, check out: http://devpinoy.org/blogs/keithrull/archive/2010/06/09/how-to-change-table-cell-color-depending-on-its-value-using-jquery.aspx